# induction on power elements in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, induction

Exercise: Prove by induction the following facts about power elements in a group. For all integers $k$ and $l$,

$(a^k)^{l} = a^{kl}$

I am having trouble with induction on two integer variables.

Attempt: I hope to show Let $P(k,l)$ denote $(a^k)^l = a^{kl}$, we need to show that for all integers $k$ and $l$, $P(k,l)$ holds.

Base Case: $P(1,1)$

$(a^1)^1 = a^{1*1}$

$a = a$

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Comment: Fix $k$, do the induction on $l$.

Comment: Does that mean, I have to consider all the cases for example, when case 1) l =0 and k >0 and k< 0. Case 2) l > 0 and k <0 and k >0. Case 3) l < 0, k >0 and k < 0?

Comment: It says all integers, if so you will need to treat positive and negative $l$ separately. If it is positive integers, the base is immediate, $(a^k)^1=a(k\cdot 1)$, and the induction step is not hard, since $b^{l+1}$ is usually *defined* as $b^l\cdot b$.